# Python - how to sort a csv file using a list

Tags: python, file, csv

I have placed data in a separate file from a quiz the user has done (by the way in the quiz the user selects one class out of three). Now I would like to  sort that data which is in the file by alphbetical, the highest score and the average score for each class.

```
if MyClass == "1":
    myFile = open('Class1.csv', 'a')
    myFile.write("Class = ")
    myFile.write(MyClass + " ")
    myFile.write("Name = ")
    myFile.write(name + " ")
    myFile.write("Score = ")
    myFile.write(str(score) + " ")
    myFile.write("\n")
    myFile.close()
elif MyClass == "2":
    myFile = open('Class2.csv', 'a')
    myFile.write("Class = ")
    myFile.write(MyClass + " ")
    myFile.write("Name = ")
    myFile.write(name + " ")
    myFile.write("Score = ")
    myFile.write(str(score) + " ")
    myFile.write("\n")
    myFile.close()
elif MyClass == "3":
    myFile = open('Class3.csv', 'a')
    myFile.write("Class = ")
    myFile.write(MyClass + " ")
    myFile.write("Name = ")
    myFile.write(name + " ")
    myFile.write("Score = ")
    myFile.write(str(score) + " ")
    myFile.write("\n")
    myFile.close()
```

this code is for saving the class into the decided file and the code below is for deciding which class they are in

```
def classes():
    #here its asking the question to the user
    theClass = input ("What class are you in: 1,2,3 ")

    # Test the input is between 1 and 3 
    while (int(theClass) > 3):
        theClass = input ("Sorry, please enter a number between 1 and 3 ")
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a csv file you're creating. It seems to build a file with lines like `Classe = 1 Name = John Lennon Score = 5` instead of `1,John Lennon,5`

Comment: The code would be much more readable with all of the `write` commands combined into one, or at least `key`,`value` pairs (one per line). Also, what is your question and desired output?

Comment: the question was just a randomized maths quiz